# gnuplot error: Cannot open script file 'plot Deaths.txt with dots'

Tags: shell, gnuplot

I am following the tutorial on this webpage
https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781849517249/1/ch01lvl1sec14/making-a-scatterplot

But when I wrote my own script

```
wget -O Deaths.txt http://www.randomservices.org/random/data/Deaths.txt
gnuplot -persist 'plot 'Deaths.txt' with dots'
```

There is an error:

```
line 0: Cannot open script file 'plot Deaths.txt with dots'
```

My terminal type: canvas

Comment: Thanks, I already know what's wrong. There should be a **-e** between -persist and the script

Answer (score 0):

The correct command：

```
gnuplot -persist -e "plot 'Deaths.txt' with dots"
```

We need an -e before running the script
(from man gnuplot)

```
   -e "command list" executes the requested commands  before  loading  the
   next input file.
```